# How to stop and start tomcat serber using azure devops pipeline

Tags: github, azure-devops

I am able to generate war using azure build pipeline then i can able deploy that war file in azure linux using azure devops but after deployment is done war file not extracrlted immediately so how to start and stop tomcat using azure devops

Comment: You can use a `powershell` or `bash` task to execute the start and stop commands on tomcat. Do you use a private agent pool or Microsoft hosted?

Comment: HI GeralexGR, How are you for deploying war file into Azure Linux Vm I am using self hosted agent(Environments).
may i know what is the cmd to stop and start the tomcat server using power shell or bash
in azure devops pipeline

Comment: What type of VM do you use? Which is the operating system of the Linux?

Comment: HI GeralexGR
We are using Azure Linux Redhat 8

Comment: You must locate the tomcat service name and use `systemctl start/stop tomcat9.service`